# Translating minimax function from Java to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, minimax, negamax

This is gonna be a big wall of code, but I hope somebody out there has the time and patience to help me.

I'm currently trying to create an AI player for my HTML Tic-Tac-Toe game. I'm using this resource which contains working AI player code programmed in Java using the minimax algorithm: https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaGame_TicTacToe_AI.html (Section 1.5)

I want to translate this given Java code to JavaScript. One major difference between the resource's code and my HTML/JS code is that the resource uses a 2-dimensional array for the game board and I use a 1-dimensional array.

That means the resource's array looks like this: `Cell[][] cells;` where the first index represents the row and the second index represents the column; and my array looks like this: `let board_array = [];` which has a length of 9 and represents the board read from top left to bottom right, so for example the top left cell is at index 0 and the center right cell is at index 5.

Another minor difference is that the resource uses player seeds to store in the cells array while I just use the strings `'X'` for the human and `'O'` for the AI.

I've spend many hours trying to translate the given Java functions to my JS script but no matter what I try, `minimax` always returns `-1` as the final best cell which, from my understanding, should only happen if there are no more available cells, indicating that the game has ended. I've done some console.log debugging and I can see that during the recursion at some point there are actually legit best cells being returned (e.g. 0 or 4) but in the final return it's always -1.

I bet that my mistake lies either somewhere in a flawed translation from the 2-dimensional array into the 1-dimensional array, or it has something to do with JS doing something entirely different than Java in a specific line. I can imagine that the binary values in the `WINNING_PATTERNS` array or the operations on them in the `hasWon` function may cause trouble. I don't know if it works like that in JS, but it doesn't throw any errors so I can't figure it out by myself.

Anyway, here's my code:

```
let board_array = ['X', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']; // X at a random index because the human player always makes the first turn
const MY_SEED = 'O';
const OPP_SEED = 'X';

function moveAI() {
  let result = minimax(2, MY_SEED);
  let best_cell = result[1];
  console.log(best_cell); // always returns -1
  // if best_cell would be properly returned I could do "board_array[best_cell] = 'O'" here
}

function minimax(depth, player) {
  let next_moves = generateMoves();
  let best_score = (player === MY_SEED) ? Number.MIN_VALUE : Number.MAX_VALUE;
  let current_score;
  let best_cell = -1;

  if (next_moves.length === 0 || depth === 0) {
    best_score = evaluate();
  }
  else {
    for (let move in next_moves) {
      move = parseInt(move);
      board_array[move] = player;
      if (player === MY_SEED) {
        current_score = minimax(depth - 1, OPP_SEED)[0];
        if (current_score > best_score) {
          best_score = current_score;
          best_cell = move;
        }
      }
      else {
        current_score = minimax(depth - 1, MY_SEED)[0];
        if (current_score < best_score) {
          best_score = current_score;
          best_cell = move;
        }
      }
      board_array[move] = '';
    }
  }
  return [best_score, best_cell];
}

function generateMoves() {
  let next_moves = [];
  if (hasWon(MY_SEED) || hasWon(OPP_SEED)) {
    return next_moves;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < board_array.length; i++) {
    if (board_array[i] === '') { next_moves.push(i); }
  }
  return next_moves;
}

function evaluate() {
  let score = 0;
  score += evaluateLine(0, 1, 2);
  score += evaluateLine(3, 4, 5);
  score += evaluateLine(6, 7, 8);
  score += evaluateLine(0, 3, 6);
  score += evaluateLine(1, 4, 7);
  score += evaluateLine(2, 5, 8);
  score += evaluateLine(0, 4, 8);
  score += evaluateLine(2, 4, 6);
  return score;
}

function evaluateLine(c1, c2, c3) {
  let score = 0;

  if (board_array[c1] === MY_SEED) { score = 1; }
  else if (board_array[c1] === OPP_SEED) { score = -1; }

  if (board_array[c2] === MY_SEED) {
    if (score === 1) { score = 10; }
    else if (score === -1) { return 0; }
    else { score = 1; }
  }
  else if (board_array[c2] === OPP_SEED) {
    if (score === -1) { score = -10; }
    else if (score === 1) { return 0; }
    else { score = -1; }
  }

  if (board_array[c3] === MY_SEED) {
    if (score > 0) { score *= 10; }
    else if (score < 0) { return 0; }
    else { score = 1; }
  }
  else if (board_array[c3] === OPP_SEED) {
    if (score < 0) { score *= 10; }
    else if (score > 1) { return 0; }
    else { score = -1; }
  }

  return score;
}

const WINNING_PATTERNS = [
  0b111000000, 0b000111000, 0b000000111,
  0b100100100, 0b010010010, 0b001001001,
  0b100010001, 0b001010100
];

function hasWon(player) {
  let pattern = 0b000000000; // does JS recognize this as a binary number like Java does?
  for (let i = 0; i < board_array.length; i++) {
    if (board_array[i] === player) {
      pattern |= (1 << (9 - i)); // does this actually do what I think it does? (compare to Java code)
    }
  }
  for (let winning_pattern in WINNING_PATTERNS) {
    if ((pattern & winning_pattern) === winning_pattern) { return true; }
  }
  return false;
}

moveAI(); // usually called after the human player sets their X
```

Comment: try putting in some debugging code.

Comment: This is not a java question. Please remove the java tag.

Comment: Binary numbers in JavaScript since ES6 - http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-literals-numeric-literals and bitwise operators in JavaScript (<<) - https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_bitwise.asp - the rest of the code should be much simpler to compare to Java? Don't think ``Number.MAX_VALUE`` will be the same as Java's ``Integer.MAX_VALUE``?

Comment: ``Number.MAX_VALUE`` (1.79E+308) is not the same as Java's ``Integer.MAX_VALUE`` (2147483647) - not sure how important that is?

Comment: @AlexL I replaced `Number.MAX_VALUE` with `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (and the same with the min value) and now the whole algorithm seems to work properly. Didn't think that would make any difference. Thanks a lot for your help.

You can post your last comment as an answer so I can accept it if you want to.

Comment: sure, happy to - thanks. Glad it helped 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary numbers are possible in JavaScript since ES6 - [ecma-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-literals-numeric-literals)

and bitwise operators in JavaScript (e.g. <<) are possible - [bitwise link](http://w3schools.com/js/js_bitwise.asp)

the rest of the code should be much simpler to compare to Java

The final difference I see:
`Number.MAX_VALUE` (1.79E+308) is not the same as Java's `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (2147483647) - not sure how important that is?